How can i change background linear gradient to tailwind in config.js to dark mode
I would like add in my tailwind.config.js linear gradient. This not is possible?
exemplo using
`theme: {
  extend: {
    colors: {
      darkGrad: {
        DEFAULT: 'linear-gradient(to bottom, #181381, #150B32, #000000, #5C2C85, #590544)',
      },
      // ... outras cores
    },
    // ... outras extensões
  },
},`

`<body class="bg-darkGrad">
  </body>
`

I think that the code not is working
`'linear-gradient(to bottom, #181381, #150B32, #000000, #5C2C85, #590544)',`


Did you install npm install tailwindcss-gradients plugin ?

You can extend background images instead.


console.clear();
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script>
  tailwind.config = {
    theme: {
      extend: {
        backgroundImage: {
          darkGrad: 'linear-gradient(to bottom, #181381, #150B32, #000000, #5C2C85, #590544)'
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<body class="bg-darkGrad">
  Some text...
</body>



Alternatively, you could simply use an arbitrary variant.


console.clear();
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<body class="bg-[linear-gradient(to_bottom,#181381,#150B32,#000000,#5C2C85,#590544)]">
  Some text...
</body>



